# Using async and await returns parsing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function that uses validate from yup and it has async function in it. 
If I want to use the whole function how can I wait for it to finish
here is code

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    companyRef.handleProfileFormSubmit();
    setModal(true);
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    console.log(companyRef.handleFocusOnError());
    if (!companyRef.handleFocusOnError() && !isButtonValid) {
      console.log('first if in handlesubmut', companyRef.handleFocusOnError());
      handleBankDetailsClick();
    }
    if (isButtonValid && !companyRef.handleFocusOnError()) {
      bankRef.handleBankFormSubmit();
      history.push(DASHBOARD);
    } else if (isButtonValid && companyRef.handleFocusOnError()) {
      setIsBankDetailsOpen(true);
    }
  };
```

I want to wait for the first sentence to finish which is

```
companyRef.handleProfileFormSubmit();
```

the async function is here

```
handleProfileFormSubmit = () => {
    const { profile } = this.state;
    const { errorValues } = this.state;
    let errorExists = false;
    let urls = url.format(profile.website.value);
    if (!startsWith(urls, 'http://') && !isEmpty(urls)) {
      urls = 'http://' + urls;
    }
    console.log(urls);

    this.schema
      .validate(
        {
          name: profile.name.value,
          industry: profile.industry.value,
          address: profile.address.value,
          crn: profile.crn.value,
          website: urls,
          employeesNbr: profile.employeesNbr.value,
          phoneNumber: profile.phoneNumber.value,
          userRole: profile.userRole.value,
          personCheck: profile.personCheck.value,
        },
        { abortEarly: false },
      )
      .catch(err => {
        errorExists = true;
        const errors = {};
        for (const i of err.inner) {
          errors[i.path] = i.message;
        }

        const sortedErrors = Object.keys(errors);
        sortedErrors.forEach(key => {
          profile[key].hasError = true;
          profile[key].errorMessage = errors[key];
          errorValues.inputErrors.value.push(key);
          this.setState({ errorValues });
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('while submitting', errorValues);
        this.handleModalError();
        if (errorExists) {
          this.props.handleCompanyError();
        }
      });
  };
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Need more info. I don't see any async functions here, is `handleProfileFormSubmit` async? What does it do?

Comment: Edited the post to show the ```handleProfileFormSubmit``` code

Comment: Curious, are you using a form library? Normally you have a submit function which is called after your form is valid and your `yup` validation schema is applied separately. In your current example you are running validation and submission at the same time, which is fine, just not how it's usually done, so you might be missing something.

Comment: At first glance you need to return `this.schema` as it looks like it's a promise, then await that in the first code block

Comment: Not, yet since its for a new project I have not gotten the okay yet on using a form library

Comment: @phix how will I be able to do that correctly?

Comment: Search for `return new Promise` at https://web.dev/promises/ for an example. Change your `handleProfileFormSubmit` into one that returns that promise. In the `this.schema.then()` handler resolve the promise. Similarly for catch/reject.

Comment: @SImonHaddad, well like I said, it's unusual to process your submission and run your validation in the same handler (see my answer below, you end up mixing concerns). You normally provide a validation schema/function and your submit handler only gets called when your form is submitted AND has passed validation.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing concerns by putting your validation and submit handler into one, but it's still possible (and fine, extract stuff into functions to make it less complicated).

Below example shows where to handle validation errors and submission errors (if submission is async, which it usually is):

```
handleProfileFormSubmit = async () => {

    try {
        await this.schema.validate({...});

        // now you know your form is valid - move on to submission
        try {
           await processSubmission(...);

           // submission successful!

        } catch(err) {
          // error occurred while submitting
        }

    } catch(err) {
       // error occurred while validating
    }

  };
```